# How to make font size output same in different div?

Tags: html, css

Just a normal HTML and body. Typical div, say two with 66.66% and 33.33 width and float:  left setting. These two five will arrange side by side but font output size are different. More over font output size of a five that is 100% width  is also different.

How to make all font size the same across different Div using only CSS?

I tried em or ch vw it turns  out messy

HTML code

```
<Body>
<div >
<Div class="col23"> anything looong</div >
<Div class="col13" > something a bit</div >
<div >
</body>
```

Styles

```
.col23 {
width: 66.66%;
}
.col13 {
width: 33.33%;
}
```

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: how could they be different?

Comment: you could assign the same css  class to both div

Comment: show us the code, reproduce the problem something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/fq7aqfbz/

Comment: Yes similar, but i used PHP to generate the HTML in wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the style to all the classes:

Since you have no code to show... here's an example:

```
<div class="left">
    Left
</div>

<div class="right">
    Right
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="left">
    Left
</div>

<div class="right">
    Right
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.left, .right {
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  height: 10em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.left {
  width: 66.66%;
  background-color: #000;
}

.right {
  width: 33.33%;
  background-color: red;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/vnsv26j6/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could include the css inline in the body tag. That would make the font the same throughout the page. If you want to change font in a particular div, just change it for that div by adding an inline for the div that you want to change.

```
 <body style="font-size:20px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use font size for complete document using   tag style.
body { font-size:14px }